# How to create all the permutations of a list based on consecutive indices as a whole list in python?

Tags: python

## This is my code (I use python 2.x):

```
import itertools

def grouper(input_list, n = 2):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list) - (n - 1)):
        yield input_list[i:i+n]

def list_of_lists(num):
    nums = list(map(int,str(num)))
    for first, second, third, fourth in grouper(nums, 4):
        x = first, second, third, fourth
        xx = list(x)
        print xx
```

## This is my input:

```
a = 1232331
list_of_lists(a)
```

## This is my output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 1]
```

## But I want the output to be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempts.

Comment: for 2: `list(zip(x,x[1:]))`. For 3?? what do you mean?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre at a wild stab - some form of "sliding window"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` method to get the combinations:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip
except ImportError:
    pass


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def getCombin(n, l):
    if len(l) < n:
        return None
    else:
        return list(zip(*(x[i:] for i in range(n))))


print(getCombin(3,x))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

If you're using Python2.x you can import `izip`:

```
from itertools import izip as zip
```

Comment: As stated above, this solution is quite fragile. Also, please don't make a habit of dumping "Try this:" and "Output:" with zero explanation, as such answers are generally unhelpful.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I update my answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I fixed it.